# How to access data from navigateOptions of Navigation Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I have a trouble with getting data from props in my Sidebar, I coded it like this using Navigation Drawer.
How can I access for example that text ("xd") from navigationOptions or how can i pass an object there
and read it correctly?

```
contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props } />, navigationOptions: {
      icon: 'xd'
  },
```

Rest of the code

```
export default Sidebar = props => (
{..Something not important in that question}
          <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} style={{
             
          }}/>
      </View>

  </ScrollView>  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly your use case is, but it might be easier to just pass `icon` directly to the `SideBar` component as a prop:

```
contentComponent: (props) => <SideBar {...props} icon="xd" />
```

Then you can retrieve the `icon` value passed to your `SideBar` component like this:

```
export default Sidebar = (props) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <Text>{props.icon}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
);
```

*I've used the `Text` component to give an example, but replace the `Text` component with the views you want.*